# Expand UITableView Header View to Bounce Area When Pulling Down

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have implemented a MKMapView in the header area and I'd like to expand it fully to the top even when you  drag down the table into the *bounce area* - Similar to Foursquare, see example:

[image: Foursquare Example]

My current default header implementation (grey bounce area when dragging down)

[image: Default Header]

How do I make the map view in the header adapt to the available header space on top when dragging the table down?

I am using the UIScrollView delegate as mentioned in the comments and then resize the map view frame as it follows.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect frame = worldmap.frame;
    frame.size.height -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    worldmap.frame = frame;  
}
```

... but it's not quite reacting correctly and performs poorly. How do I set the new size of the map frame correctly?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979323/new-foursquare-venue-detail-map

Answer (score 6):

Implement the scrollview delegate for table view. Since it is a subclass of scrollview you can use the scrollview delegates. Implement `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate and whenever it scrolls down, change the frame of headerview and make sure the pin always comes in the center of the screen.

Include `UIScrollViewDelegate` in .h file and implement,

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  //set the frame of MKMapView based on scrollView.contentOffset and make sure the pin is at center of the map view
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the right way. However I have issues to get resizing work correctly. I've tried to to it with "CGRect frame = worldmap.frame; frame.size.height -= scrollView.contentOffset.y; worldmap.frame = frame;" But it doesn't quite work right.

Comment: @BerndPlontsch, What is the problem you are facing with that?

Comment: The frame size doesn't match (a problem with the assigned value?) and the redrawing performance is quite slow on my Phone5 and in the Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Make your headerView frame very long, then center the map in a region that allows you to view the interesting area in bottom of the map.

**Edit:**
I've notice that the pin in the Foursquare example stays in center of the map. This means that you probably should use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to use `didScroll` method and change the frame of the map dynamically during the scroll. You should also center the map in the pin's region while scrolling.

Comment: How to implement this change? When I stretch the map view in Interface Builder then the map view gets bigger but the area in the bounce area stays unchanged.

Comment: I never use Interface Builder... You should change the map frame in `didScroll` method, using scrollView contentOffset.
Interface Builder is evil ! You'll lost the control of your app whit it.

Comment: Please see my current edit. I am using the didScroll method now and try to resize the map but unfortunately it doesn't quite work out yet.

Comment: Have you change the header view of table ?

Comment: Hm. I can resize the height now with the value from the scrollView.contentOffset.y parameter from scrollViewDidScroll delegate. The problem is that the origin of the tableHeaderView stays were it is. So I need to move its frame to a negative value. This doesn't seem to work

        [[[self tableView] tableHeaderView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, worldmap.frame.size.width, 150-scrollView.contentOffset.y)] ; //150 is the original height as a fixed value.

Comment: I tried the same with negative frame positioning values for the maps frame. That does't work neither: [worldmap setFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, worldmap.frame.size.width, 150-scrollView.contentOffset.y)];

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I've implemented this in a project.

TableView header is a MapView and as an added bonus the map can also be moved and zoomed.

https://github.com/danielbowden/DBParallaxMapTableView

Answer (score 0):

I put the content of the header view inside another view which I constrain to each side of the header view. Then using an IBOutlet to the top constraint I just set it to the contentOffset.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_tableView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        _mapTopConstraint.constant = _tableView.contentOffset.y;
    }
}
```