# Information on this view

Tags: ios, uiview, mapkit

What is the view called (I refer to it as a 'map detail view'), and is it possible to create an instance of it with my own data and my own custom buttons?

[image: Map Detail View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this isn't a system view exposed to developers in the iOS SDK. There may be 3rd-party equivalents however I have never seen one.

Check out the list of classes for MapKit here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html

This question may help you too: [New foursquare venue detail map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979323/new-foursquare-venue-detail-map). Although not identical, I think it explains how that cool effect on the top works.