# How to make a pull-up View in iOS (similiar to FourSquare)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to make a a sliding up like FourSquare app.
Like this:

[image] [image]

What I want to achieve are:

- The `UITableView` goes all the way up to `UINavigationBar`.
- It drags along with my finger's position.
- My app also have a `GMSMapView` below (Google Map's API, similiar to FourSquare), I don't want the map responses to my gestures on the `UITableView`, I want it stays still.
- Works both in iOS 6 and 7 and iPhone 4,5.

Does anybody have a framework, github's link ... that can help me fulfill this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on something very similar in the past days. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979323/new-foursquare-venue-detail-map) answer is actually quite good, but you will suffer a bit in terms of performance. After more tweaking, I used parts of [this](https://github.com/mstrchrstphr/LocationPickerView) library. You don't need to use everything, but keep in mind the following when choosing a library:

1. Libs that base the movement of the map on the `map.centerCoordinate` are less performant than libs that base the movement on the map's `frame`.

You can also read a bit from this [tweets exchange](https://twitter.com/XSody/status/418418906001186816) I had.

---

My thoughts about what FourSquare actually did, is that in the beginning they are using a screenshot of the map, so they are not really using a `MKMapView`, but an `UIImageView`. Once you touch it and you animate it, they switch between one and another and they start using a map. I will be using Reveal App plus [this](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-3rd-party-apps/) to know exactly what they are doing.

Comment: Hey, since you have worked a pull up view. What would you recommend for me? My background view is a simple view controller and my pull up view is a UITableView. Thanks.